# How to use ARGV in cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver, argv

How can i whrite argv. in cucumber-test?

I want, that my test run at localhost:3000 and than on productions (live).

I want this with argv. to define.

```
ARGV.each do |s|
  if s == `-d`
    @text = `localhost:3000`
  elsif   s == `-p`
    @text = `www.world.com`
  end
end
```

Comment: Running tests on production is scary business.  Why do you need to do this?  If your tests are written such that they don't tear down the database between test runs then I'd say you aren't testing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick test, it looks like you can include your code as-is in your env.rb file. The `@test` variable would then be available in all your steps.

(I am not sure if it is a best practice, but it does work.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Fig Newton](https://github.com/cheezy/fig_newton) to solve that kind of problem. You can have many different *environments* that you can call at execution time. It's easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create bin directory and put there cucumber.rb file with your ARGV logic.

Then when you run smth like:

`ruby bin/cucumber.rb -u 'http://www.ololo.com'`

This script will :

- setup you test environment ( set @url or write to env.yml to 'http://www.ololo.com')
- run 'cucumber' command.

Or you can use this: [How do I specify the browsers in my cucumber.yml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833071/how-do-i-specify-the-browsers-in-my-cucumber-yml-files?rq=1)