# How do I specify the browsers in my cucumber.yml files?

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver

I want to create cucumber profiles and specify the browsers I want to run the tests on in my profiles. For example my cucumber.yml looks like:

```
default: @chrome --tags @sanity1 --require features
firefox: @ff--tags @sanity1 --require features
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an [environment variable](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Environment-Variables) for the browser type. Then in your test, use that variable to determine the browser to create.

For example, you could add a BROWSER variable to your cucumber.yml profiles:

```
default: BROWSER=chrome
firefox: BROWSER=firefox
```

Then when you create a browser, say in the before hook, you would check the ENV variable:

```
Before do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new ENV['BROWSER']
end
```

Note that if the browser value is lowercased it can be passed directly into the initialization of the Watir::Browser. If you want to use a different value (eg "FIREFOX" instead of "firefox"), you will need to use a case statement to evaluate it.

When you use the profile, it will use the specified browser.

To run the tests in chrome:

```
cucumber
```

To run the tests in firefox:

```
cucumber -p firefox
```